# Why Does the TableView Show Under the Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, navigationbar

I set my navigation bar to be transparent at the start. I also set a `UIlabel` at the top of my `ViewController` if it does not need to be transparent. This works for `UIViewController`, but if I use `UITableViewController`, I cannot add a `UIlabel` at the top of my view, because it is embedded with the `UITableViewController` and scrolls with the `TableView`. Below is a sceenshot which looks the `TableView`.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: cant understand what you saying, give some code first

Comment: how can I add a `uilabel` on top of the view when I use `UITableviewController` , without scrolling it with the tableveiw

Comment: you use `UIViewController` and implement `UITableView`+your custom view on top of it, and dont use `UITableviewController ` anymore, its only for pure `UITableView`, if you wish to add custom view on top of tableView, just do it with `UIViewController`

Comment: no the thing is I use the tableview for a from. that means custom cells with uitextfields. because it scrolls automatically when keyboard appears. so how can I do to with UITableview

Comment: you can use header property in UITableviewController

Comment: @DeeprajChowrasia he dont want it scroll with the table view so cant use it as header, maybe can use it with tableView section cell

Comment: @bill u can add tableview in `UIViewControlle` also, dont need use `UITableviewController `

Comment: yes @Tj3n is right ..that's much better and easy option in this case

Answer (score 1):

A UITableViewController can only be used if its `view` is just the table. This means that your view controller can't be a UITableViewController unless the table occupies the *whole* scene.

To work around this in a legal way, you need to construct a custom parent view controller, like this:

```
ViewController
    child: UITableViewController
```

The ViewController's `view` now contains the label and the table view controller's `tableView`. Problem solved.

You can very easily configure this in the storyboard using a Container View to stand for the table view in the ViewController scene. Indeed, this is probably one of the most important uses of a Container View.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tableview in UIViewController on place of UITableViewController.
In case of UITableViewController use it as fixed header and just uncheck the bounces of UITableViewController in utility area.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in your `viewDidLoad`

```
  if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```